# Why would VBA use an array of string type instead of just the string as a argument

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I am coding in Excel VBA and recorded a Macro to see how MS would perform an action I am trying to write.
In the code, I noticed how they put a string inside an array like below.

```
.CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT *" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM `C:\Temp\test.accdb`.myTbl myTbl")
```

Can someone explain to me why use an array in this fashion?

Wouldn't it be easier to use just the string as such:

```
.CommandText = "SELECT *" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM `C:\Temp\test.accdb`.myTbl myTbl"
```

Comment: The macro recorder isn't what I'd call smart.  Note how it also used `Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10)` instead of `vbCrLf`. This has less to do with how *Excel* would perform an action as it does with how the *macro recorder* interprets what Excel is doing.

Comment: Great point.  I agree the recorder isn't very smart.

But is using an array like this, best practices?

Comment: the recorder is actually very dumb. lets clear the array and grab some pizza

Comment: IIRC there used to be a limit of 255 characters for the SQL/CommandText properties of some objects, which could be circumvented by using an array of strings (each element was still limited to 255 characters) - hence what the recorder does.

Comment: Thanks Rory.  Answers my question and understanding.  It does make since in that case.